# Can't install pymssql on Manjaro - compilation issues?

Tags: python-3.x, pymssql, manjaro

I want to install pymssql in my virtual env (Python 3) in order to use it in Django app. My OS is Manjaro, I have already installed FreeTDS (and configure freetds file accordingly to Arch Wiki) and msodbcsql. However, I still can't install pymssql and here's error traceback:  https://gist.github.com/szpone/0e494c388e5a105ed274da8c97b3e945

Answer (score 1):

So apparently all I had to do is download the latest version of pymssql directly from git - `pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git`. I tried this earlier, but for some reason, pip couldn't finish installation.